# Interpretation of model

Tags: machine-learning, model-evaluation

I have two models $Y$ ~ $X_1 + X_5$ and $Y$ ~ $X_2 + X_4$ ($Y$ is Binary). Both models produce different coefficients using training data, predicted probability using testing data and ROC curve using testing data.

But they give same AUC value. How can I define or interpret this?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what the two 'models' are ? model comparison depends on that.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your models are pretty much equally efficient, so maybe all four features are relevant. Have you tried a model that incorportaes all of them?